# Add Item in a ComboBox that is not in a BindingList

Tags: c#, combobox, listbox, items

I have two repositories, one has a `BindingList` of objects (which can have a tag) and the other one has a `BindingList` of tags, simple strings. The objects and the tags can be created dynamically.

In a `Windows Form` I have a `ListBox` with my objects listed, and a `ComboBox` with the tags (the `ListBox` and `ComboBox` are binded to the `BindingLists` in the repositories)... My ideia is to select a tag from the `ComboBox` and show in the `ListBox` all objects with that tag. I managed to do that...

Now my problem... I want to have a tag "All" that gets me all the objects, and that tag "All" can only be shown in that `ComboBox` (I have other forms with ComboBoxes that cant show that tag "All", I just need this tag to filter).

So if I add the tag "All" to my repository I will see that tag in all `ComboBoxes`... and I dont want that... I cant remove it from the other `ComboBoxes` because they are binded... and I cant add it to that `ComboBox` for the same reason...

Anyones knows how can I solve this?

Comment: Adding to the BindingList before setting that list as datasource of your combo?

Comment: If I do that I will see the tag "All" in all the ComboBoxes binded to the BindingList, I just want that tag to be shown in one specific ComboBox.

Comment: Uhm, I see, if the T is not too big you could duplicate it via BindingList.CopyTo and add the required item to the new copy

Comment: So I should have a second binding list (copy of the first one), and add the tag "All", and then bind that specific ComboBox to that new copy of BindingList?

Comment: The problem are the other ComboBoxes that share the same list. I can't see a different approach if one exists.

Comment: Oh, well. If you want you could add a checkbox with "Select all". When checked you could disable the combo, when not checked you could enable the combo

Comment: Thats actually a better idea! I prefer it versus the duplicated BindingList. Thank you very much!